# How to save a record using visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, create-records

I have a site using visualforce dbvc.force.com/MRSurvey when I try to save a record with this, it does not allow it and tells me authorization is required, even though the site is public. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?  Also, can I have some suggestions as to where those records will go once saved, will it automatically create a new tab or where could I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the the object is public. Else you need to authorize to save the record.

Ensure the site profile and check you have added all the component that are accessible through site.

See this
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites

Comment: All of the components are accessible from what I can see. I've checked again and still directing me to the authorization page?

Comment: Go to Site --> click your site name -> Clikc  Public access setting button -> click on object you want to give permisison and marrk (Read, Create, Edit, View All).  Ensure that what are all the object utilized in vf code should have rigght access in that profile.

Comment: That is all done. The issue I am having is getting the record to save, once I enter the details on the site, I can access the site externally, but cannot save the record, once I hit the "Save" button it asks for authorization, but on my other sites I have set-up the same way it works perfectly. I actually copied this site from one of the existing ones and changed the pages and code for the new site.

Comment: Do I need to add any triggers or other mechanisms to carry the data from the fields onto my Organisation's Salesforce page?

Comment: No. something the public profile don't have access to process save action. which object you are updating ?  do you have any re-direct code. ?  Check the data is saved in db before getting.

Comment: This is the code I am using for the site:
<apex:page standardController="MR_Evaluation__c" showHeader="false"> 
    
    <apex:sectionHeader title="DBVC Maintenance Request Evaluation"/>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Evaluate Maintenance Request" columns="1">

Comment: <apex:inputField value="{!MR_Evaluation__c.Evaluation_Ref__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!MR_Evaluation__c.Maintenance_Request_Ref__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!MR_Evaluation__c.MR_Eval__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!MR_Evaluation__c.Comments__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: Do you have any loop up ? what is this filed Evaluation_Ref__c ?

Comment: Evaluation_Ref_c will be a reference number for the record that is being created by the page.

Comment: Sorry. I can suggest to create debug log for the site user and try to click save button. Look at the debug log. you can get the exact error.